# Line chart Interactive Zooming in SSRS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, report, reporting, ssrs-2012

[Please find attached example image, mark red color as zoom points.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqBij.png)

I want to achieve interactive zooming in line chart, I come to know using SSRS its not feasible. Can you please suggest any software or tool can achieve zoom functionality which can be integrated in SSRS.

Currently i am using drill-down to show another chart

If user drag on particular mark the chart should be zoom on that point.

Comment: I think this is not possible in SSRS. But if in case someone with more experience has already tried it can add more here.

Comment: yes @AnkUser, So looking anybody using 3rd party tool to achieve this functionality.